# PHP: Basic exiftool usage

Tags: php, exiftool

I am trying to use exiftool (because it has all image tags vs. other tools) on a webserver. The perl module is installed in /bin/exiftool

The test.jpg is the same directory and has EXIF data.

```
<?php
#!/usr/bin/exiftool

$array = [];

eval(`$array=` . `exiftool -php -q test.jpg`);

print_r($array);
?>
```

The $array is empty though. I also tried:

```
eval(`$array=` . `exiftool -php -q test.jpg > output.txt`);
```

This creates an empty output.txt file.

I feel I have something very basic wrong but can't work it out. Like to add, I am on a shared host and have root/command line access.

---

No Update: I still struggle. I think it's related to cgi / perl (or my lack of knowledge about it)

Comment: On a shared host, is `eval()` enabled for your use? It is commonly disabled. Any error output in your error log? To be honest, I would not use the `eval()` approach with the php output array. Instead, I would probably use `\`exiftool -json...\`` for JSON output then load it with `json_decode()`.

Comment: When executing a shell command with backticks in PHP, it is also advisable to use the full path `/bin/exiftool`, as you cannot rely on it to have a sane `$PATH`.

Comment: @Michael, `eval()` works, I tried with: `eval("echo 'Hello World!';");`. I know, json is more elegant, but for now I am only on a test server. Adding the path did not make it work.

Comment: Not so much that `eval()` is inelegant, but more that when you are not in control of both ends of the code generation and consumption, it introduces risks. (exiftool is probably trustworthy)

Comment: Thank you, my question wasn't really about `eval()` though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `exec()` function for that:

```
$exifToolPath = 'cgi-bin/exiftool';
$exifToolParams = '-G';

// Read EXIF from jpg
$img = 'test.jpg';
exec($exifToolPath.' '.$exifToolParams.' '.$img, $data);
var_dump(array_unique($data));

// Read EXIF from NEF
$img = 'test.NEF';
exec($exifToolPath.' '.$exifToolParams.' '.$img, $data);

// Read XMP
$img = 'test.xmp';
exec($exifToolPath.' '.$exifToolParams.' '.$img, $data);
sort($data);
var_dump(array_unique($data));
```

You can also [install exiftool](https://www.speich.net/articles/en/2018/01/21/how-to-install-exiftool-with-composer/) with composer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `exiftool` is a Perl program and thus external code to PHP. I think `eval` is not probate to run external code. Try `exec`.

Datahardy.